# 16-Digit Code Shows Hidden Download Link?

Tags: hyperlink, download

Could anyone point me in the direction of having a a form on a website, consisting of just a text field, that reveals to a download link when they punch in the correct 16-digits?

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you only using javascript?

Comment: Even if they use only JS, they will eventually change it after realizing its insecure.

Comment: @doitlikejustin Using PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of what you can do.

Your input field like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="digits">
</form>
```

Your PHP:

```
if($_POST['digits'] == '1234567890123456')
{
    $download_link = TRUE;
}
else
{
    $download_link = FALSE;
}
```

Then where you want the download link on that page to show:

```
if($download_link === TRUE)
{
    echo '<a href="/link/to/download/">Download Link</a>';
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to do a POST request but stop the browser from taking you to another page. For example, is there a way to give you access to the download link by it fading in upon inputting the correct 16-digit code? Similar to icloud.com.

Comment: Yes that is very possible. You would need to use Ajax for this. Here is a good article that can help you out. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/ Read through the whole article and it will all make more sense but what you really want to work with is #5 on that link... `$.post()` Requests